# ArrayList that has Rectangles, is being passed as an Object

Tags: java, object

Hi i am getting the error in the console:

```
no suitable method found for intersects(Object)
            if((EnemyBarrels.get(i).getHitBox()).intersects(buildG.getStepD().get(i))){
                                                ^
method RectangularShape.intersects(Rectangle2D) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Rectangle2D)
method Rectangle.intersects(Rectangle) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Rectangle)
```

I dont understand what is happening because getStepD returns an ArrayList.

Here is the code:

EnemyBarrels contains multiple objects.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < EnemyBarrels.size(); i++){
            EnemyBarrels.get(i).move();
            if((EnemyBarrels.get(i).getHitBox()).intersects(buildG.getStepD().get(i))){
 }
```

And this is getHitBox():

```
public Rectangle getHitBox(){
    return hitbox;}
```

This is hitbox:

```
Rectangle hitbox = new Rectangle(BarrX,BarrY,25,21);
```

In which BarrX and BarrY are ints.

This is getStepD():

```
public ArrayList getStepD(){
    return stepD;
}
```

This is stepD:

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> stepD = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

Which contains rectangles.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: `public ArrayList getStepD`... You return a raw list of Object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning an ArrayList in your getStepD method, because you dont specify which type of objects your ArrayList contains in the method. Java assumes you are returning an ArrayList of objects. You could change your method to this

```
public ArrayList<Rectangle> getStepD(){
    return stepD;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, didnt know that. Thank You!